# Water Heater Exhaust - how to connect the 3 inch hood to four inch exhaust pipe

Tags: water-heater, gas, ducts, exhaust-vent

I'm working on this gas water heater with 3" hood almost attached to an elbow that reduces from a 4" exhaust flue. This was only attached by a lot of aluminum tape. The problem is that the ends of both sides are exactly the same size. What parts do I need to do this properly?

Here is a picture of the current situation

[image: bad fitting exhaust duct]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might want to take our tour to see how the site operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3" coupling made for this. They are available at home stores and heating ans AC supply stores.
[image]

You'll probably need a few sheet metal screws or go back to some aluminum tape.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be pretty but there isn't anything wrong with using aluminum tape on this. However, there are other options.
There are a number of reducers and elbows that will fit:
[image]
This is a 3" to 4" adaptor that should get you started and can be combined with a flexible elbow:

[image]
These are American Metal Products available at HD. You may have to do some adjusting - ductwork is as much art as science. If these particular items don't work for you there are others out there.